# What could cause all the breakers on the left side of my panel box to trip?

Tags: electrical

I added a double pole breaker in my panel box for a dryer receptacle. When I finished, I noticed the refrigerator was out - and the microwave. Went back to the panel and noticed that ALL the breakers were tripped on the left side. Reset them and all is OK.

The breaker I had just added was on the right side. House is about 4 years old. I can't imagine I tripped a bunch of breakers just by simply reinstalling the panel box cover. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This has happened to me.  You may have just manually tripped the breakers when you were putting the cover back on.  It doesn't take much force to trip the breaker.

It's unlikely that an electrical mis-wiring caused this, because each side of the box is fed alternatively by both of "hot" feed.  Say you have split phase 1 and 2.  The left side of your box will be fed by phase 1, 2, 1, 2, etc.  The breakers on the left side have nothing in common with each other that they don't also have in common with the right side.

Comment: I also had this happen and it was when I was putting the cover back on.  It slipped a bit when they tripped, and it makes sense I just bumped them all.